# Disable the hash-conversion for params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-sortable

The [nestedSortable Plugin](https://github.com/ilikenwf/nestedSortable) sends this POST-Parameter (via *serialize*):

```
chapter[87]=null&element[377]=87&chapter[88]=87
```

It describes a tree of chapters and elements. **The order of the items in the string is important!**

- Chapter 87

  - Element 377
  - Chapter 88

When I access the params in the controller, the ordered string is converted to a hash, so the order is lost:

```
{"chapter"=>{"87"=>"null", "88"=>"87"}, "element"=>{"377"=>"87"}}
```

Is it possible to disable the built in hash-conversion or do I have to alter the content of the POST, so that Rails can't convert it to a hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work directly with the request:

```
 request.body.string
```

depending on your setup, try `request.body.read` since its basically an IO

Comment: I get the following error: undefined method `string' for #<PhusionPassenger::Utils::TeeInput:0x00000004e4ed10>

If I change the code to request.body.read, it works! So thanks for your input!

Comment: ah, I guess it depends on the webserver :)